# (sort of) casting types in Ruby: changing class of an instance

Tags: ruby, casting

I defined the class `Rectangle`:

```
class Rectangle
  attr_reader :b, :h
  def initialize(b, h)
    @b = b
    @h = h
  end
  def area
    @b*@h
  end
  def to_s
    "Rectangle #{@b}x{@h}"
  end
end
```

and its subclass `Square`:

```
class Square < Rectangle

  attr_reader :s
  def initialize(s)
    @s = s
    super(@s, @s)
  end
  def to_s
    "Square of side #{@s}"
  end
end
```

Now, let's say I defined a Rectangle object `r = Rectangle.new(5, 5)`, but actually it should be a `Square` because I'd like `r.to_s` to return `"Square of side 5"`.

I can define a `to_square` method in the `Rectangle` class that returns a `Square` object equivalent to `r`, but, is it possible to write a `to_square!` method that would actually change the `r` class to `Square` without returning another object, so that `r.class` would now return `Square` instead of `Rectangle`?

And, what if I'd like:

```
Square(r)
```

to return the `Square` equivalent object of `r`, just like:

```
Integer("3")
```

which returns the Integer `3`?

Is that possible? And, if so, *how*?

Comment: Don't close questions if you can migrate them to SO!

Comment: the hall monitors strike again. i wish you guys wouldn't do this. i got here from google, it was exactly what i needed and rather then find help, i find know it alls telling the submitter and me how stupid we are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, why bother with a separate `Square` class?

Personally, I'd make a `Rectangle` class' `to_square!` method simply set both width and height to `Math.sqrt(area)`. The result is still a `Rectangle`, just a square one.

The Rectangle's initializer method could also be written with an optional second argument; If there's only one argument, use that for both width and height, and you have a square.

Furthermore, I'd add a `square?` method. Checking `obj.square?` is, in my view, preferable to checking `obj.class == Square`. You could also use `square?` in `to_s` to return one string or the other.

To answer your question, though, I don't know of any way to just change an instance's class. You could however experiment with including different modules depending on whether the rectangle in question is a square or not. But that all seems pretty complex.

Finally, if you want a `Square` *method*, simply define one:

```
def Square(side)
  Rectangle.new(side, side)
end
```

Even if you have a `Square` *class* already, you can still have a *method* of the same name:

```
class Square
  # ...
end

def Square(side) # no naming conflict
  Square.new(side)
end
```

Comment: Because I'm studying inheritance and subclassing :-)

Comment: @DuccioArmenise Ah, well that explains it :) In that case, I'd definitely go with tokland's suggestion of a factory method on the class, or a `Square()` factory outside the class (like you see above), and/or have `Rectangle#to_square` (no bang) return a new `Square` instance. Don't start changing the class of an instantiated object, even if you can (and again, I doubt you can - it'd get confusing in a hurry).

Comment: Ok, but what about if `r`, instance of `Rectangle`, can't be converted in a Square because it isn't a square. _Conventionally speaking_, it would be right to assume that `r.to_square` should return `false` while `r.to_square!` should raise an exception?

Comment: @DuccioArmenise Depends on what you want to enforce. I imagine a `to_square` that returns a square with the same area as `r`, regardless of whether `r` is already a square. Same as calling `to_i` on a float returns an int even if the float can't be perfectly expressed as an int; `to_i` doesn't raise. Alternatively, you _could_ have a `to_square` that raises an exception for a non-square `r`, while a `to_square!` forcibly returns a "squared square". However, in this context, I'd say that's a bad use of the bang-suffix.

Comment: Just found this statement of Matz's about it: "The bang (!) does not mean "destructive" nor lack of it mean non
destructive either. The bang sign means "the bang version is more dangerous than its non bang counterpart; handle with care" (http://www.wobblini.net/bang.txt) And, from the Pickaxe: "Methods that are dangerous, or that modify their receiver, may be named with a trailing exclamation mark" (http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html). :-)

Comment: @DuccioArmenise Exactly, I just didn't have enough characters left to write all that :) - Since most bang methods in Ruby mean "modify the receiver", it's a little iffy to use one to return another object; that doesn't seem "more dangerous", so to speak. You could however have a bang method that turns a rectangle into a "square rectangle" by setting its sides to the same value - but you can't have one that turns it into an instance of `Square`. So it'd be misleading to have both `to_square` and `to_square!`, where one returns a `Square` obj, and the other changes the `Rectangle`... dilemma! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the expression `ClassName.new` return something different than an instance of `ClassName` you will be breaking the programmer's expectations. The most idiomatic, and simple, way is writing a factory method:

```
class Rectangle
  # same code you have

  def self.with_sides(b, h)
    b == h ? Square.new(b) : Rectangle.new(b, h)
  end
end

Rectangle.with_sides(1, 2).to_s # Rectangle 1x2
Rectangle.with_sides(2, 2).to_s # Square of side 2
```

Of course, you can always do [black magic with Ruby's new](http://ola-bini.blogspot.com.es/2007/12/code-size-and-dynamic-languages.html), but I'd advise against it.

Comment: Really interesting answer and article, thank you. But I didn't ask for `ClassName.new` to return something different from an instance of `ClassName`. Instead I asked if it's possible to change the class of an existing instance in Ruby (I guess it's not possible, as in Java, and for good reasons, but I don't know for sure yet). And I agree with @Flambino when he sais that even if it would be possible it would be a bad idea.